# How to scroll a slide to top in slick carousel on slide change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

As there is no method to make swipe tabs without using libraries, I decides to use slick to create this tabbed content using slick itself.

The tabs are working perfectly but when content in one slide exceeds the other, the the slides don't automatically scroll to top on slide change. we have to maually scroll to top of next slide manually.

How can we remove this behavior in slick carousel?

Scroll to the bottom of the first tab, the swife left to load the content of next tab, we can see that it doesn't scroll to the top.

My code so far:

```js
$(function() {
  'use strict';
  $('.tabContainer').slick({
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.tabContent',
    arrows: false,
    infinite: false,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    touchThreshold: 10,
  });
  $('.tabContent').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.tabContainer',
    arrows: false,
    infinite: false,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    touchThreshold: 10
  });
  /* On Slide Change, Scroll the div .tabcontent to top */
  $('.tabContainer').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    $(".contentItem").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, "fast");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh
}

.tabContent {
  overflow-y: hidden
}

.contentItem {
  overflow-y: scroll!important;
  /*not working*/
  width: 100%/*not working*/
}

.tabItem.slick-current {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px red;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="tabContainer">
    <div class='tabItem'>Tab01</div>
    <div class='tabItem'>Tab02</div>
    <div class='tabItem'>Tab03</div>
    <div class='tabItem'>Tab04</div>
    <div class='tabItem'>Tab05</div>
    <div class='tabItem'>Tab06</div>
    <div class='tabItem'>Tab07</div>
    <div class='tabItem'>Tab08</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabContent">
    <div class="contentItem">Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/>Content1<br/></div>
    <div class='contentItem'>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/>Content2<br/></div>
    <div class='contentItem'>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/>Content3<br/></div>
    <div class='contentItem'>Content4<br/>Content4<br/>Content4<br/>Content4<br/>Content4<br/>Content4<br/>Content4<br/>Content4<br/>Content4<br/>Content4<br/>Content4<br/>Content4<br/>Content4<br/>Content4<br/>Content4<br/>Content4<br/></div>
    <div class='contentItem'>Content5</div>
    <div class='contentItem'>Content6</div>
    <div class='contentItem'>Content7</div>
    <div class='contentItem'>Content8</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you ever solved this?

Comment: @DennisFink I ended up using `$("html").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "fast");` in place of `$(".contentItem").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "fast");`

Comment: Thanks @YourPalNurav, Your answer solved my issue.
Thanks!!!